# FTP Upload in JAVA

Tags: java, upload, ftp

I want to use FTP to upload a file with a Java application, but it's not working.

The problem is that if I do the FTPUploader class in my main class, it works perfectly, but if I do like it's in here, it doesn't work. Can you guys help me out?

My code is:

Main Thread:

```
package restrictedareamanager;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class RestrictedAreaManager {

    File path = new File ("C:\\Área Restrita");
    File lista[] = path.listFiles();

    public void processa () throws IOException {

        String titulo, subtitulo, nomeArq, aux;

        for (File s : this.lista) {
        aux = s.getName();

            //String work
            titulo = aux.substring (0, aux.indexOf ("-"));
            aux = aux.substring (aux.indexOf ("-")+1);
            subtitulo = aux.substring (0, aux.indexOf ("-"));
            aux = aux.substring (aux.indexOf ("-")+1);
            nomeArq = aux.substring (0);

            //Create new file to be copied
            final File dest = new File (path + "\\" + nomeArq);

           //Copy File
           FileCopier copiador = new FileCopier();
           copiador.copiaArquivo(s, dest);

            //Send file via FTP
            FTPUploader ftp = new FTPUploader("**********", "********", "*********", titulo, subtitulo, dest);
            ftp.execute();  

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        RestrictedAreaManager ram = new RestrictedAreaManager();
        ram.processa();

    }
}
```

FTPUploader class:

```
package restrictedareamanager;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class FTPUploader extends SwingWorker <Object,Object> {

    private String servidor;
    private String usuario;
    private String senha;
    private String titulo;
    private String subtitulo;
    private File dest;

public FTPUploader (String servidor, String usuario, String senha, String titulo, String subtitulo, File dest) {

    this.servidor = servidor;
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.subtitulo = subtitulo;
    this.dest = dest;

}   

@Override
protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient ();

            try {  
             ftp.connect("servidor");  

             //verifica se conectou com sucesso!  
             if( FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion( ftp.getReplyCode() ) ) {  
                 ftp.login ("usuario", "senha");  
             } else {  
                 //erro ao se conectar  
                 ftp.disconnect();  
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro ao se conectar com o servidor FTP", "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    
                 System.exit(1);  
             }  

                 ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                 ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/download");
                 ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(this.titulo);
                 ftp.changeWorkingDirectory (this.subtitulo);

                 ftp.storeFile (dest.getName(), new FileInputStream (dest.getPath().toString()));
                 System.out.println ("Done");


             ftp.logout();
             ftp.disconnect();  

             } catch( IOException | HeadlessException e ) {  
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro ao enviar o arquivo.", "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
                 System.exit(1);  
             }

   return null;
}

}
```

Comment: what's not working? we need more descriptive problem information, as well as any stack traces that are generated by thrown exceptions, etc. Also, see my post below for an alternate way to do this.

Comment: Hey @SnakeDoc, thanks for answering. Well it takes a while to upload the file (2mb file), it seems like it's doing the upload, also it prints messages like 'Done!' after the upload, but when I go and check it with FileZilla, it's just not there (unless I put everything in main class, then it works). It's not throwing exceptions. I saw your way to do that, but must learn first, because it's a bit different. Any possible way to deal with my version?

Comment: is this a linux or windows box that you are FTP'ing to? Are you able to check the FTP logs on the server? Perhaps somethign on that end is blocking (permissions, etc?)

Comment: @SnakeDoc Hey, thanks for answering! I've switched my upload function to Util.copyStream (), i'll check the log and tell you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check into JSch library - it handles all the ugliness of FTP and sFTP connection in java.

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Here's a sample implementation (from live production code):

```
package com.somecompany.productfeed;

import net.snakedoc.jutils.ConfigException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class SFTP {

    // setup logger
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SFTP.class.getName());

    private JSch jsch;
    private ChannelSftp sftpChannel;
    private Session session;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String host;
    private int port;

    // singleton
    private volatile static SFTP instance = null;

    /**
     * Private constructor used in Singleton pattern.
     *     All variables populated via properties file upon 
     *     object instantiation. Since we only need FTP to one server,
     *     object variables are immutable after instantiation.
     * 
     * @throws ConfigException
     * @throws NumberFormatException
     */
    private SFTP() throws ConfigException, NumberFormatException {

        this.jsch = new JSch();
        this.username = Config.getInstance().getConfig("SFTP_USER");
        this.password = Config.getInstance().getConfig("SFTP_PASS");
        this.host = Config.getInstance().getConfig("SFTP_HOST");
        this.port = Integer.parseInt(Config.getInstance().getConfig("SFTP_PORT"));

    }

    /**
     * Create or Return SFTP Object using Singleton pattern.
     * 
     * @return Singleton of SFTP Object.
     * @throws NumberFormatException
     * @throws ConfigException
     */
    public static SFTP getInstance() throws NumberFormatException, ConfigException {

        if (SFTP.instance == null) {

            synchronized (SFTP.class) {

                if (SFTP.instance == null) {

                    SFTP.instance = new SFTP();

                }

            }

        }

        return SFTP.instance;

    }

    /**
     * If connection is not already open/connected, open connection.
     * 
     * @throws JSchException
     */
    public void openConnection() throws JSchException {

        LOG.info("Opening SFTP Connection");
        if (null == getSession() || ! getSession().isConnected()) {

            setSession(jsch.getSession(this.username, this.host, this.port));
            getSession().setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            getSession().setPassword(this.password);
            getSession().connect();

            Channel channel = getSession().openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            setSftpChannel((ChannelSftp) channel);

        } else {

            LOG.info("SFTP Connection already open");

        }

        LOG.debug("Success");

    }

    /**
     * Closes connection.
     */
    public void closeConnection() {

        LOG.info("Closing SFTP connection");
        getSftpChannel().exit();
        getSession().disconnect();
        LOG.debug("SFTP Connection closed");

    }

    /**
     * Checks if SFTP Connection is open.
     * 
     * @return TRUE if connection is open, FALSE if connection is closed
     */
    public boolean isOpen() {

        if (getSession().isConnected()) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }

    /**
     * Gets SFTP Channel
     * 
     * @return SFTP Channel (<code>ChannelSftp</code>)
     */
    private ChannelSftp getSftpChannel() {

        return this.sftpChannel;

    }

    /**
     * Returns current <code>Session</code>
     * 
     * @return <code>Session</code>
     */
    private Session getSession() {

        return this.session;

    } 

    /**
     * Sets SFTP Channel (<code>ChannelSftp</code>)
     * 
     * @param sftpChannel Channel to set this object's <code>ChannelSftp</code>
     */
    private void setSftpChannel(ChannelSftp sftpChannel) {

        this.sftpChannel = sftpChannel;

    }

    /**
     * Sets current <code>Session</code>
     * 
     * @param session Sets this object's <code>Session</code>
     */
    private void setSession(Session session) {

        this.session = session;

    }

    /**
     * Pushes local file to remote location
     * 
     * @param local String representation of filepath + filename (ex: /some_local_directory/somefile.txt)
     * @param remote String representation of filepath + filename (ex: /some_remote_directory/somefile.txt)
     * @throws SftpException
     */
    public void push(String local, String remote) throws SftpException {

        LOG.info("Sending file: " + local + " to remote: " + remote);
        getSftpChannel().put(local, remote);
        LOG.debug("Success");

    }

    /**
     * Gets remote file to local location
     * 
     * @param remote String representation of filepath + filename (ex: /some_remote_directory/somefile.txt)
     * @param local String representation of filepath + filename (ex: /some_local_directory/somefile.txt)
     * @throws SftpException
     */
    public void get(String remote, String local) throws SftpException {

        LOG.info("Retrieving file: " + remote + " saving to: " + local);
        getSftpChannel().get(remote, local);
        LOG.debug("Success");

    }

}
```